# Question on basic understanding of DLL , #include and __declspec(dllimport)

Tags: c++, dll, include, dllimport

I am doing my first dll in C++ / VS. I did a Client-Project as well as a DLL, LIB using functions with __declspec(dllimport) . Everything works fine but now I have a basic question that may sound silly:

I know that there are lots of advantages using dlls like reuse of code, speed, etc.

From the programming-structure point of view **is it correct to say that there is not much of a difference in using dlls compared to using #includes?** You would have the same amount of #includes in your files e.g. have the same structure in which file #includes another file etc? The only change you would need to do to your code in order to create a dll is to add *__declspec(dllimport)* in front of the functions you want to export and only build the project instead of compiling? Is that right?

Comment: If not using dll, you also need add the cpp files of the lib to your project.

Comment: there are a huge number of differences - to name but one, the code in the dll can be loaded into your program at run-time (so you could replace the dll with something else)  whereas the c++ source in includes and .cpp files is purely compile-time. there are lots of other differences.

Comment: *Dll*s and *#include*s are not mutually exclusive but complementary, as they are used in different phases (build, run) and the former depends on the latter.